# How to get validation of input field and button to play nice?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

I have the following input field:

```
<input id="filename" type="text" name="filename" onchange="checkfilename()"></input>
```

A button:

```
<button onclick="openSave()">Save</button>
```

I have the following functions:

```
        function openSave()
        {
            var filename = document.getElementById('filename').value;
            if(!filename || filename.trim()==="")
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Do some work to save file
                mySaveFunction();
            }
        }

        function checkfilename()
        {
            var input = document.getElementById('filename');
            input.value = input.value.trim();
            var vals = input.value;
            if(!vals || vals==="")
            {
                clearerrormessage();
                var statusMessageDiv = document.getElementById("errormessage");
                var errorTextNode = document.createTextNode("You forgot to specify a filename.");
                statusMessageDiv.appendChild(errorTextNode);
            }
            else
            {
                clearerrormessage();
            }
        }
```

When I input nothing in the input field, and leave, or click on the button, it works as expected and the error message is displayed and `mySaveFunction()` is not called.

Immediately after this, if I go back to the text field, enter some text, and then IMMEDIATELY click on the button, the error message is cleared, but `mySaveFunction()` is not called! I have to click on the button one more time to get mySaveFunction() to execute! Why does this happen and how can I fix it? The bug repros every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

As I was updating the dom while I was clicking on the button, the button moves away from the pointer just enough so that the "click" didn't complete.

The second time I was clicking on the button, the dom wasn't changing, so the click could complete.

I fixed it, by ensuring my button was not moving when I clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FBhaR/) and look at the `javascript console`

```
<input id="filename" type="text" name="filename" onchange="checkfilename()"></input>
<button onclick="openSave()">Save</button>
<div id="errormessage"></div>


function openSave(){
    var filename = document.getElementById('filename').value;
    if(!filename || filename.trim()==="") {
        return;
    }else{
        //Do some work to save file
        console.log("save");
    }
}

function checkfilename(){                
    var input = document.getElementById('filename');
    input.value = input.value.trim();
    var vals = input.value;
    if(!vals || vals===""){
        console.log("clear message")
        document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "";
        var statusMessageDiv = document.getElementById("errormessage");
        var errorTextNode = document.createTextNode("You forgot to specify a filename.");
        statusMessageDiv.appendChild(errorTextNode);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "";   
    }
}
```

Comment: your fiddle works, but my actual javascript has the problem, probably because my funcs are manipulating the dom and not just outputting to the console. Not sure how to debug this.